# Maven: WSDLException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target (Even i installed jssecacerts to security)

Tags: java, maven, cxf, webservice-client, wsdl2java

Following is maven plugin:

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-sources</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated/cxf</sourceRoot>
                            <wsdlOptions>
                                <wsdlOption>
                                    <wsdl>https://wd2-impl-services5.workday.com/ccx/service/fietu1/Human_Resources/v34.0?wsdl</wsdl>
                                </wsdlOption>
                            </wsdlOptions>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Following is error:

> Caused by: javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException: faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: Problem parsing 'https://wd2-impl-services5.workday.com/ccx/service/fietu1/Human_Resources/v34.0?wsdl'.: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
>
> Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
>           at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)

[image]

I have followed all steps till end from [here](https://mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/suncertpathbuilderexception-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target/). I.e generated jssecacerts and copied it in JDK/JRE path.

Then rerun in eclipse and still getting same issue. I have not used keytool yet as my system earlier has some office related keys installed through keytool and i am not sure whether this certificate will hinder existing ones?

Comment: Double-check that the JDK/JRE that you installed jssecacerts on is the same that Eclipse uses to run maven

Comment: Also, have you tried to run Maven from the command-line?

Comment: @areus: i restarted system and the error has gone. What the hell is that?